# In a Rails form, using one submit button to send data for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am creating a survey with the following data model:`MathTest has_many math_questions`

On `MathTest#update` I want to create one form for every question.  The form should look something like this:

```
<%= form_for(mathtest) do %>
  <% math_question.each do |question| %>
    <%= f.label :answer %>
    <%= f.text_field :answer %>
    <%= f.hidden_field math_question.id %>
  <% end %>

  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I want to send the MathTest Controller a set of tuples with a math_question id and the answer for that question.  Then in the Controller, I can call another method that evaluates each question's answer.

How do I write my form to send the appropriate tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<%= form_for(mathtest) do |f| %>
  <% math_question.each do |question| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answer do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.label :answer %>
      <%= ff.text_field :answer %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Also edit the model:

```
class MathTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :math_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :math_questions
```

fields_for documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: You also need to put 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :math_questions' in your math test model

Comment: I would also consider adding the cocoon gem.

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class` Where it refers to the following line: `<% f.fields_for question.answer do |ff| %>`.  Not sure why, but check this pastie for the slightly modified version of your answer I tried: http://pastie.org/private/padhgvgrllayh20nedpxq